# Multiple variables as table name

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I currently am working with this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $tables(serial,date,type,file,size) VALUES('$serial','$date','$test','$final_file','$new_size')";
        mysql_query($sql);
```

Where $tables is a sigle variable. I now need to replace $tables with names like "sam_coll" using two different variables such as $device and $test as below;

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $device_$test(serial,date,type,file,size) VALUES('$serial','$date','$prova','$final_file','$new_size')";
```

The page then gives me "unexpected '_' (T_STRING)". 
How does the table name need to be written?

Comment: you can't use vars for  table name you must use the table name directly

Comment: But i am able to connect to different tables with a single variable, what's the difference? Is the underscore a problem with mysql?

Comment: @scaisEdge he can use variables as table name because he build a string, when he try to build table name like that but with prepared statemet then he can't do that. I think problem is trivial with undeclared variables, sfasas after build $sql print it to screen and die script to see what was build

Comment: You should get "undefined variable device_" because it's ambiguous.  Try `{$device}_{$test}`

Comment: @PiotrLasota ... you're right ..

Answer (score 0):

Although many considerations, you can concatenate strings like that:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO ".$device."_".$test."(serial,date,type,file,size) VALUES('$serial','$date','$prova','$final_file','$new_size')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically I use the concatenation method for building out queries like that because to me it is easier to read:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO " . $device . "_" . $test . "(serial,date,type,file,size) VALUES('" . $serial . "','" . $date','" . $prova . "','" . $final_file . "','" . $new_size . "')";
```

But you could also just put curly braces around the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much! I was stuck on this for an hour.. (I am learning php for a project we are doing at work so i don't know many things)